# rbind() overwriting rows of matrix in loop

Tags: r

I have the following matrix "myMatrix2":

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
[4,]    1    2    3
```

Now I want to write a function which puts all the rows beginning with the value 1 in a new matrix.

This is what I came up with:

```
retrieverows_2 <- function(matrixold, y=1){
  matrixnew <<- matrix()
  while(y<=nrow(matrixold)){
    if(matrixold[y,1]==1){
     matrixnew <<- rbind(matrixold[y,])
    }
  y <- y+1
  }
}
```

The problem now is, that it seems to overwrite the row of the new matrix so that it only returns the last row of my initial matrix as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
```

My desired result though would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    1    2    3
```

Can maybe someone explain to me why `rbind()` overwrites the row of my new matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not iterativey append/`rbind` for simple scenarios like this. Instead use subsetting:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,3), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
newmat <- m[which(m[,1] == 1),]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    1    2    3
```

As for WHY your code only returns one line, you are rewriting `newmatrix` every time. You need to create a counter to keep track of new rows. Something like

```
  count = 0
  while(y<=nrow(matrixold)){
    if(matrixold[y,1]==1){
      count = count + 1
      matrixnew[count,] <<- rbind(matrixold[y,])
    }
    y <- y+1
  }
```

But all of this should be replaced with subsetting.

Comment: thank you very much, that finally worked. and as you pointed out, subsetting seems way more practical so I'll use that in the future